# Were all the Kauravas married?

Tags: mahabharata, kauravas, duryodhana

Two common things among most Kshatriyas were:

- Marrying many women
- Having many children

If we see most kings described in the Puranas, most of them seem to have met with these two conditions. These are valid too, as it was necessary to propagate your dynasty so that you could maintain your line as well as efficiently rule your kingdom once one expanded it by conquering other kingdoms.

We know that Dhritarashtra had a hundred and one sons, out of whom the prominent sons are Duryodhana, Duhshasana and (due to his role in Draupadi's Mana Samrakshana) Vikarna. But even though Vyasa lists out the other Kauravas, as far as I know, the only Kaurava described living a family life is Duryodhana, who married Bhanumati, the princess of Kalinga, and had two children - Lakshmana (who was slain by Abhimanyu in battle) and Lakshmanaa (who married Krsna's son Samba).

So, does Vyasa give any information as to whether the other 100 brothers (including Yuyutsu) were married, and whether they had children?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the other lesser-known Kauravas were also married and had children but Vyasa and the other Mahabharata characters don't seem to address their wives and children by their first names.

In Abhimanyu-vadha upa-parva of Drona Parva, Duhsasana's son [strikes](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07046.htm) Abhimanyu with his mace:

> Next, he [Abhimanyu] slew ten car-warriors of the Brahma-Vasatiya race, and then ten huge elephants. Proceeding next towards the car of **Duhsasana's son**, he crushed the latter's car and steeds, pressing them down into the earth. The invincible son of Duhsasan, then, O sire, taking up his mace, rushed at Abhimanyu. saying, 'Wait, Wait!' Then those cousins, those two heroes, with upraised maces, began to strike each other, desirous of achieving each other's death, like three-eyed (Mahadeva) and (the Asura) Andhaka in the days of old. I ach of those chastisers of foes, struck with the other's mace-ends fell down on the earth, like two uprooted standards erected to the honour of Indra. Then **Duhsasana's son**, that enhancer of the fame of the Kurus, rising up first, **struck Abhimanyu with the mace on the crown of his head**, as the latter, was on the point of rising. Stupefied with the violence of that stroke as also with the fatigue he had undergone, that slayer of hostile hosts, viz., the son of Subhadra, fell on the earth, deprived of his senses. Thus, O king, was one slain by many in battle

In Stri Parva, Gandhari [laments](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m11/m11018.htm) her dead sons along with their wives and also her son-in-law (Duhshala's husband):

> Gandhari said, ‘There, O Madhava, **my son Vikarna**, applauded by the wise, lieth on the bare ground, slain by Bhima and mangled horribly! Deprived of life, O slayer of Madhu, Vikarna lieth in the midst of (slain) elephants like the moon in the autumnal sky surrounded by blue clouds. His broad palm, cased in leathern fence, and scarred by constant wielding of the bow, is pierced with difficulty by vultures desirous of feeding upon it. **His helpless young wife**, O Madhava, is continually endeavouring, without success, to drive away those vultures desirous of feeding on carrion. 
>   ... 
>   ... 
>   At that time, O Janardana, when Jayadratha, assisted by the Kekayas, endeavoured to ravish Draupadi, he deserved to be slain by the Pandavas! From regard, however, **for Duhshala, they set him free on that occasion**. Why, O Krishna, did they not show some regard for that Duhshala once more? That daughter of mine, of tender years, is now crying in grief. She is striking her body with her own hands and censuring the Pandavas. **What, O Krishna, can be a greater grief to me than that my daughter of tender years should be a widow and all my daughters-in-law should become lordless.**

Answer (score 3):

Yes all of the kauravas were married. It is mentioned that each of the hundred brothers had found a wife for themselves.

Quote:

> "And, O, king, worthy wives were in time selected for all of them by
>   Dhritarashtra after proper examination."

[Adi Parva is the first book of Mahabharata, and this is a section that proves what i am saying.](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01118.htm)