# What were the names of the Kauravas' wives?

Tags: mahabharata, kauravas

In one of the answers to [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12233/were-all-the-kauravas-married) question, there's a [link to a passage from the Adi Parva.](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01118.htm) The passage lists all the Kauravas and ends by telling us that

> Worthy wives were in time selected for all of them by Dhritarashtra after proper examination. And king Dhritarashtra, O monarch, also bestowed Duhsala, in proper time and with proper rites, upon Jayadratha (the king of Sindhu).

So I know that they were all married. However, I can't find any list or text where we can see the names of those women that they married. I know that later folk retellings say that Duryodhana was married to Bhanumati (although the original says nothing), and it seems that Dushasana was married to Jyotsyana and that Vikarna was married to Mridula, a Kashi princess, but I can't find much beyond that.

So, what *are* the names of the Kaurvas' wives?

Comment: Not mentioned in the story. They’re irrelevant

Comment: From where did you get Jyotsyana, Mridula and an apsara? This is the first time I'm coming across these names :O

Comment: @Surya - Mridula was a Kashi Princess, according to Wikipedia's entry for Vikarna. For Jyotsyana, see here: https://bhagavanbhakthi.com/2022/10/pandavas-and-their-children-upapandavas-names/#:~:text=Dushasana%20wife%20name%20is%20Jyotsyana,Kunti%20Devi%20and%20Madri%20Devi.. And Chitrasena's marriage to an apsara was actually a silly mistake I made. (That was Chitrasena the Gandharva- I'll fix that)

Comment: the names of kaurava wives including bhAnumatI are nowhere mentioned in vyAsa mahAbhArata. bhAnumatI is the name of a wife of sahAdeva - http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/vishnuparva/hv_2_090.html

Comment: @ArvindC - She is not in the Vyasa Mahabarata; she was added in later from folk retellings. I should clarify in my question that answers needn't be from the original version. (See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhanumati_(Mahabharata)#:~:text=Bhanumati%20is%20the%20wife%20of,is%20added%20in%20later%20versions.)

Comment: @Heartspring exactly my point, that's why I pasted the link of original version where a person named bhanumati is actually the wife of sahadeva

Comment: @ArvindC , I have adjusted the question accordingly. That's interesting that Bhanumati was Sahadeva's wife; I had not known that before.